# Excel auto fit column in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have here my code in VB6 and its working well.

```
 For CLms = 1 To 10
      ws.Columns(CLms).AutoFit '<---Autofilt data on XL sheet
 Next CLms
```

I have searched on what is the equivalent or alternative on how to make the excel columns width autofit in VB.NET, but I'm still not getting the exact AutoFit function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I've done it in vb.net.

```
xlSheet.Range("A1:X1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

Comment: @user2878699: Your code is not "working well". In VBA, without `.EntireColumn`, `.AutoFit` does nothing! This solution is correct for VBA - not VB6, vb.net, ...

Comment: @Aphoria, thanks for the help. Maybe this is not the complete line of code but this example got the functions I will be needing, it depends on the developer on how he construct his code to work. Again Thanks!

Comment: It worked perfectly fine in my environment.  The only change I has was to change it to:
`xlSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()`

Answer (score 1):

For example if you don't know the number of columns you can autofit the complete Row.

```
xlSheet.Rows.Item(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods for manipulating an Excel column are the same regardless of whether you are calling the code from VB6 or VB.NET. So there should be no change to your code if it works in VB6.

However for some help - Have a look at [this full example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982/en-us) in VB.NET that includes autofit

Comment: I have read the link you gave and I have applied it to my project and now it's working well like what I expected.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hello i try all these solution..but no one was work..
please take the right solution:

```
    With oSheet

        .PageSetup.Zoom = False
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [@RPh_Coder comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359866/excel-auto-fit-column-in-vb-net/74061964#comment60299485_19359973), you can also do this by:

```
xlSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the ff. codes to autofit the used range.

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```