# VB.NET Excel AutoFit columns

Tags: excel, vb.net, pivot

I did created the pivot table using vb.net. 
For some reason i cant format that PivotTable or either set the column width to autoresize.

Here is what ive tried

```
xlBook.ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, xlSheet.Range("A1:J" & ukupno))
' Creating pivot table here ...
With xlBook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Data")
    .Caption = "Zarade"
End With

xlApp.CommandBars("PivotTable").Visible = False
xlBook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

xlSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
xlSheet.Range("A1:J1").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
With xlSheet

    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

End With
xlSheet.Range("D3:J" & ukupno).NumberFormat = "#,####0.00_);[Red](#,####0.00)"

xlApp.Visible = True
```

None of those worked for me : [excel-auto-fit-column-in-vb-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359866/excel-auto-fit-column-in-vb-net)

Edit : Also tried with

```
xlSheet.Range("A:F").Columns.AutoFit()
xlSheet.Range("A:F").ColumnWidth = AutoSize
```

Comment: Use `xlSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit()` and remember to call it _after adding the data_.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed that doesn't help me. The last line of code is to adjust the size of column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `xlSheet` to add pivot table. For some reason posting column formatting to `xlSheet` wont affect.

So i changed the approach to

```
xlBook.Worksheets("Pivot").Range("C:F").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)"
```

And this solved my problem.